# Default format datetime Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, django-1.6

I have a project in Django 1.6 and a configuration file called formats.py, it is defined as I want the date to appear in my project.
In my settings I tell the FORMAT_MODULE_PATH the path to that file,but Django is ignoring this file and whenever I have the need display date use filters.
How do I stop the default date format in the project?

My formats.py

```
 DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'
 DATETIME_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
 DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y', '%d/%m/%y', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

in my settings i use:

```
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = 'myproject.formats'
```

Structure:

myproject /
      formats /
         **init**.py
          pt_BR /
                **init**.py
               formats.py

Comment: What does your directory structure/tree look like. Where is your **formats.py** located?

Comment: Please show your directory structure. In particular, where is `formats.py` located?

Comment: Ready. edited. Sorry.

Comment: @Vanderson could you check if renaming `pt_BR` package to `pt` helps?

Comment: unfortunately not helps. :(

Comment: You need an `__init__.py` in your formats folder as well as each language folder

Comment: Does switching `USE_L10N` value change anything?

Comment: @alecxe change, but does not resolve.

Comment: @Vanderson ok, what does `import locale;print locale.getdefaultlocale()` print?

Answer (score 1):

You need an `__init__.py` in your formats folder as well as each language folder

```
myproject /
    formats /
        init.py  # <----- 
        pt_BR /
            init.py
            formats.py
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#format-module-path)